# Cheking if my POST value is in my array

Tags: php, arrays

I received by POST a value (duration) which contain 6 for instance .

I want to check if this value is in my array, i found this function, but it's not working for me.

```
$duration = $_POST['duration'];

    // Constantes pour l'abonnement
    $suscribe = array(
        'prices' => array(
            1=>10,
            3=>25,
            6=>50,
            )
        );

        if (in_array($duration, $suscribe['prices']))
        {
            echo 'this array contains '.$duration.'';
        }
```

Comment: it works like charm for me. you sure you are checking for the value in array?

Comment: @sunny What code have you been trying? o,o

Comment: The same he provided, i just hardcoded $duration to 10 for testing purpose

Comment: @sunny Umm, he wants to check the key not the value "_which contain 6 for instance_"

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger  Yes i know now, but at a first glance to the question, it looked like he was searching for values!

Comment: @I Can Has Cheezburger , actually i didnt read the first line of his question, sorry! my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Use array_key_exists, not in_array, as you are searching for the key, not the value

```
$duration = $_POST['duration'];

// Constantes pour l'abonnement
$suscribe = array(
    'prices' => array(
        1=>10,
        3=>25,
        6=>50,
        )
    );
    //you are searching for a key, not a value
    if (array_key_exists($duration, $suscribe['prices']))
    {
        echo 'this array contains '.$duration.'';
    }
```

Comment: Oh ok, so if i wanted to check for the value i will have to use in_array ? It's working thanks .

Comment: @Brian Thats correct, and as raina says, you can also use isset, although the two functions are not the same